# ckan add source url using java client

Tags: java, ckan

I am trying to add the source URL on an existing resource but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have:

```
HttpEntity reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
           .addPart("id", new StringBody("resource id",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
           .addPart("Source", new StringBody("www.google.com",ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))          
           .build();
postRequest = new HttpPost(host+"/api/3/action/resource_update");
               postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
               postRequest.setHeader("X-CKAN-API-Key", "myApi");
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
"success": false, "error": {"__type": "Validation Error", "url": ["Missing value"]}
```

I can add a `Source` field when I upload a file, but it doesn't create a link for it. Maybe because I use `ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN` instead of something that will tell CKAN that this is a link?

Edit:
By source I mean the link on the resource information where it points to the webpage of the original data. When manually uploading a file you have that option, I just cant get it to work with the API.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're trying to upload a file or provide the URL of the file. Please clarify that and also provide a screen shot of the web form that you're trying to emulate in the API.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you've not specified the `url` value for the resource, which is necessary.

The content that you POST needs to be in JSON format, whereas you appear to be sending it as multipart form data.

The JSON keys you need to send for a resource are `id`, `url`, `name`, `format` etc. i.e. you need to set `url` rather than `Source`. You can see the existing keys by looking at `/api/action/resource_show?id=xyz`.

The normal way to use resource_update is to do resource_show first, edit the JSON with the new values, and then resource_update. That way you don't lose any other properties of the resource, such as format.

Comment: According to the ckan doc, for the resource update, it only needs the id, not the url. What is url anyway? When u do a manual ipload u can have the source field that works jjust fine

Comment: The mandatory fields for a resource are determined by the dataset schema, so changes if you configure it, which is why it isn't mentioned in the doc for resource_update. The URL is the location of the data - it is the most important part of the resource. When you do an upload in the CKAN web interface then the field is still called "URL" as far as I can tell. Are you trying to upload a file? If so, you cannot use resource_update for that.